# Pass some data with viewpager.setCurrentItem(position)

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I want to passes some value inside button click with viewpager tab fragment changing. I have two question.

1. what is the best way to passes data?
2. If I use static data what will be problem? such like:

   ```
   public static string abc=""

   case R.id.IVActionMore:   
   ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs_viewpager);
   viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
   //abc = "action";
   break;
   ```

Comment: have you tried **addOnPageChangeListener**

Comment: Well for me there is no problem in using static string, I also use it to pass some info around

Comment: I only dabbled in Android development, but there were Context objects you should use to put data. A static is not a great idea because they aren't controlled by the lifecycle concept, so your App may be reloaded without noticing and the data is gone.

Comment: yes I also tried only for tab change but how can I passes data. and what will be the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shared-preference to set and get the data. using static is not a great idea. check the link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/4549220

Comment: Is it best way to passes data ?

Comment: You can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885276/how-to-share-same-data-between-multiple-activities-in-android

Answer (score 1):

1. Use **[addOnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener))**

> void addOnPageChangeListener (ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener)
>   Add a listener that will be invoked whenever the page changes or is
>   incrementally scrolled.

**How ?**

```
 viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float 
                     positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) 
    {

     if(position == 3)
     {
           // DO your work
     }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

**OnClick**

```
 buttonOBJ.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
   {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v)
             {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, true);
             } 
   });
```

Comment: I want to change page on button click.

Comment: thanks for your replay. but "Don't use STATIC . It's not good approach". what is the best approach? and how can i use that in your code.

Comment: @t.gakk No problem for `static` . But aware from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472690/in-java-is-there-any-disadvantage-to-static-methods-on-a-class

Comment: @t.gakk For data passing case, Use SharedPref . http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-shared-preferences-in-android/28370

Comment: Is it best way to passes data ?

Comment: @t.gakk i use `sharedpref` not problem yet

Comment: @t.gakk for your above question, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities